# Missing file after remove cocoa pods

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I remove cocoa pods from my project, but when compile the project I see error : "Missing file". What can I do to avoid any such warnings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These warnings are not build warnings, they are about your SVN repository. It is correct that the directories shown no longer exist, CocoaPods stores the headers in Pods/Headers/{Private,Public} now. You have to update your working copy to reflect those changes.

So, you should `commit` it!

So, you can manually remove them,

```
  svn delete "nameFile"
```

Reference:https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3341